# Include a Sharepoint Calendar on an meeting invite from Outlook

Tags: sharepoint-calendar, outlook, spcolor

If I include a Sharepoint calendar on an invite from Outlook, is there a way for the calendar to pull information from the title and automatically selects the category which in turn automatically changes the view/color of the invite to the colors on the calendar for that particular category/overlay?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You could extract the category from the invite title with a SharePoint Workflow, and then set the color with javascript on the page.  Please advise which version of SharePoint you are using, as the specific details will depend on the features you have available to you.

Comment: I am using SP 2013. Although 'attempting to use' would be more accurate!